# VVP can't compile

Tags: system-verilog

I do have a problem with compiling my code :

```
module alu(i_a, i_b , i_oper, o_y, o_status, i_rsn, i_clk);
parameter BITS = 4;
parameter OPER = 3;
input logic signed [BITS - 1:0] i_a, i_b;
input logic [OPER-2:0] i_oper;
input logic i_clk;
input logic i_rsn;
output logic signed [BITS - 1:0] o_y;
output logic [3:0] o_status;
logic [BITS - 1:0] o_y_mux;
logic [BITS - 1:0] o_y_1;
logic [BITS - 1:0] o_y_2;
logic [BITS - 1:0] o_y_3;
logic [BITS - 1:0] o_y_4;
logic [3:0] o_status_mux;
logic [3:0] o_status_1;
logic [3:0] o_status_2;
logic [3:0] o_status_3;
logic [3:0] o_status_4;

ashift_example1 #(.BITS(BITS)) case1 (.i_a(i_a), .i_b(i_b), .o_arith_left(o_y_1), .o_error(o_status_1));
U2_to_ZM #(.BITS(BITS)) case2 (.i_a(i_a), .o_zm(o_y_2), .o_status(o_status_2));
porownanie #(.BITS(BITS)) case3 (.i_a(i_a), .i_b(i_b), .o_smaller(o_y_3), .o_error(o_status_3));
replace #(.BITS(BITS)) case4 (.i_a(i_a), .i_b(i_b), .o_replaced(o_y_4), .o_error(o_status_4));

always_comb
begin

{o_y_mux, o_status_mux} = '0;
case (i_oper)

2'b00 : o_y_mux = o_y_1;
2'b01 : o_y_mux = o_y_2;
2'b10 : o_y_mux = o_y_3;
2'b11 : o_y_mux = o_y_4;
default : o_y_mux = '0;

endcase
case (i_oper)
2'b00 : o_status_mux = o_status_1;
2'b01 : o_status_mux = o_status_2;
2'b10 : o_status_mux = o_status_3;
2'b11 : o_status_mux = o_status_4;
default : o_status_mux = '0;
endcase
end

always_ff @(posedge i_clk)
begin
if(i_rsn == 1)
begin
o_y <= o_y_mux;
o_status <= o_status_mux;
end
else
begin
o_y <= '0;
o_status <= '0;
end
end
endmodule
```

This is the code for the module (the module is a multiplexer).Below is testbench :

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module test_alu;

parameter BITS = 4;
parameter OPER = 3;
logic signed [BITS - 1:0] i_a, i_b;
logic [OPER-2:0] i_oper;
logic i_rsn;
logic i_clk;
logic signed [BITS - 1:0] o_y;
logic signed [BITS - 1:0] o_y_rtl;
logic [3:0] o_status;
logic [3:0] o_status_rtl;



alu #(.BITS(BITS), .OPER(OPER)) alu (.i_a(i_a), .i_b(i_b), .i_oper(i_oper), .o_y(o_y), .o_status(o_status), .i_rsn(i_rsn), .i_clk(i_clk));
//exe_unit_38_rtl alu_rtl (.i_a(i_a), .i_b(i_b), .i_oper(i_oper), .o_y(o_y_rtl), .o_status(o_status_rtl), .i_rsn(i_rsn), .i_clk(i_clk));

initial
begin
$dumpfile("alu.vcd");

$dumpvars(0,test_alu);

i_rsn = 1;
i_clk = 0;
i_oper = 2;
i_a = '0;
i_b = '0;
#1
i_clk = 1;
i_oper = 1;
i_a[3] = 1;
#1
i_clk = 0;
i_oper = 3;
i_b[3] = 0;
i_a[3] = 0;
i_a[2] = 1;
i_a[0] = 0;
#1
i_clk = 1;
i_oper = 0;
i_a[0] = 0;
i_b[1] = 1;
i_a[3] = 1;
#1

$finish;
end
endmodule
```

Here are also the modules that the multiplexer needs :

```
module ashift_example1(i_a, i_b, o_arith_left, o_error);
parameter BITS = 4;
input logic signed [BITS-1:0] i_a, i_b;
output logic signed [BITS-1:0] o_arith_left;
output logic [3:0] o_error;

integer x;
always_comb
begin
x = 0;
o_arith_left = '0;
o_error = '0;
if(i_b >= 0)
begin
o_arith_left = i_a <<< i_b;
if(i_a < 0)
begin
o_arith_left[BITS-1] = 'd1;
end
else
begin
o_arith_left[BITS-1] = 'd0;
end
end
else
begin
o_error[0] = 1;
o_arith_left = 'x;
end
for (int i = 0; i<BITS;i++)
begin
if(o_arith_left == 1)
begin
x = x+1;
end
end
if (x % 2 == 0 && o_arith_left != '0)
begin
o_error[1] = 1;
end
if(o_arith_left == '1)
begin
o_error[2] = 1;
end
end
endmodule

module U2_to_ZM (i_a , o_zm, o_status);

parameter BITS = 4;
input logic signed [BITS-1:0] i_a;
output logic signed [BITS-1:0] o_zm;
output logic [3:0] o_status;
logic signed [BITS-1:0] one;

integer x;
always_comb
begin
x = 0;
one = i_a;
o_status = '0;
if(i_a < 0)
begin
for (int i = 0; i<BITS-1; i++)
begin
one = ~i_a;
end
if(one == '1)
begin
o_status[3] = 1;
o_status[0] = 1;
o_zm = 'x;
end
else
begin
o_zm = one + 1;
end
end
else
begin
o_zm = one;
end
for (int i = 0; i<BITS;i++)
begin
if(o_zm == 1)
begin
x = x + 1;
end
end
if (x % 2 == 0 && o_zm != '0)
begin
o_status[1] = 1;
end
if (o_zm == '1)
begin
o_status[2] = 1;
end
end
endmodule

module porownanie(i_a, i_b, o_smaller, o_error);
parameter BITS = 4;
input logic signed [BITS-1:0] i_a, i_b;
output logic signed [BITS-1:0] o_smaller;
output logic [3:0] o_error;

always_comb
begin
o_error = '0;
o_smaller = '0;
if(i_a<=i_b)
begin
o_smaller = 'd1;
end
else
begin
o_smaller = '0;
end
if(o_smaller == '1)
begin
o_error[2] = 1;
end
end
endmodule

module replace(i_a, i_b, o_replaced, o_error);
parameter BITS = 4;
input logic signed [BITS-1:0] i_a, i_b;
output logic signed [BITS-1:0] o_replaced;
output logic [3:0] o_error;

integer x;
integer i;
always_comb
begin
x = 0;
i = 0;
o_replaced = '0;
o_error = '0;
if(i_b < 0 || i_b > BITS)
begin
o_error[0] = 1;
o_replaced = 'x;
end
else
begin
i = i_b;
o_replaced = i_a;
o_replaced = 1;
end
for (int i = 0; i<BITS;i++)
begin
if(o_replaced == 1)
begin
x = x+1;
end
end
if (x % 2 == 0 && o_replaced != '0)
begin
o_error[1] = 1;
end
if (o_replaced == '1)
begin
o_error[2] = 1;
end
end
endmodule
```

The problem is that the Multiplexer works in Windows but doesn't work in Linux I don't know why ...

Whenever I use vvp it says that it made the VCD code but the terminal doesn't respond to anything and the VCD code that I open on gthwave doesn't want to open like it is not a vcd file

Comment: Since this is probably a tool issue, you will need to provide all the steps used to run your code.

Comment: the command I use is 1 : iverilog -o test.vvp -g2005-sv Module.sv(file with all 4 modules) exe_unit_38.sv (module with alu) exe_unit_38_testbench.sv 
2. vvp test.vvp 3.gtkwave

Comment: But the vvp test.vvp crashes

Comment: Looks like this is a tool issue, you should ask for support at an icarus verilog forum. Stackoverflow forum is about (verilog) programming only.

Comment: Where can I find such a support ?